# angular2 event not firing

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I am using angular2, I have a dropdown list and I have a function to be called on the `(change)` event. But this event is not firing. The below is my code

```
    import {Component, EventEmitter, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
    import {perPageCount} from './interface';
    import {CORE_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/common';
    @Component({
    selector: 'table-content',
    template: 
     `<div class="dropdown-wrap ">
          <select name="" tabindex="1" (change)="onSelect($event.target.value)">
                  <option *ngFor="#perPageCount of perPageCounts; #i=index" value="{{perPageCount.value}}" [attr.selected]="i == 0 ? true : null" > 
                                    {{perPageCount.text}} 
                  </option>
          </select>
     </div>`,
    providers: [CORE_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class tablecontent {
    public perPageCounts: perPageCount[] = [
        { text: 10, value: 1 },
        { text: 25, value: 2 },
        { text: 50, value: 3 },
        { text: 100, value: 4 }
    ];
    public ipp: number = this.perPageCounts[0].text;

    onSelect(value) {
        this.ipp = null;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.perPageCounts.length; i++) {
            if (this.perPageCounts[i].value == value) {
                this.ipp = this.perPageCounts[i].text;
                console.log(this.ipp)
        }
    }
}
```

The dropdownlist is loading but `onSelect(value)` function is not firing! Please somebody help!!

Comment: Which version of Angular do you use?

Comment: @ThierryTemplier 2.0.0-beta.7

Comment: Thanks! Why do you set `CORE_DIRECTIVES` into the providers attribute?

Comment: Actually I was doing a trial & error method.. I also put `CORE_DIRECTIVES` in directives attribute .. but showing the same result

Comment: In fact, you don't need anymore to set them ;-)

Comment: okay.. Did that solve the problem?

Comment: Could you add the list of libraries you include in your HTML page?

Comment: @ThierryTemplier List of libraries :es6-shim/0.33.3/es6-shim.min.js,
0.19.20/system-polyfills.js,2.0.0-beta.7/angular2-polyfills.js, tools/system.js, tools/typescript.js, 2.0.0-beta.7/Rx.js, 2.0.0-beta.7/angular2.dev.js, 2.0.0-beta.7/router.dev.js

Comment: I can't reproduce on my side with your code and the libraries you use. Which browser do you use?

Comment: browser I use is Google chrome

Answer (score 2):

I updated a bit your code since I have TypeScript error but it works on my side. The `onSelect` method is called:

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/common';

class perPageCount {
  constructor(public text: number, public value: number) { }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'first-app',
  template:
    `<div class="dropdown-wrap ">
      <select name="" tabindex="1" (change)="onSelect($event.target.value)">
        <option *ngFor="#perPageCount of perPageCounts; #i=index" value="{{perPageCount.value}}" [attr.selected]="i == 0 ? true : null" > 
          {{perPageCount.text}} 
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>`
  })
export class AppComponent {
  public perPageCounts: perPageCount[] = [
    new perPageCount(10, 1),
    new perPageCount(25, 2),
    new perPageCount(50, 3),
    new perPageCount(100, 4)
  ];
  public ipp: number = this.perPageCounts[0].text;

  onSelect(value) {
    this.ipp = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.perPageCounts.length; i++) {
      if (this.perPageCounts[i].value == value) {
        this.ipp = this.perPageCounts[i].text;
        console.log(this.ipp)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tested your code like this as well and I have the same behavior (the `onSelect` method is called)...

Perhaps you forget to include the `Rx.js` file into your HTML page:

```
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script> <-------
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
```

Comment: Do you have the `Rx.js` library included into your HTML page?

Comment: I solved the issue. actually issue was related to Jquery UI. a function called createDropdown() has been fired from jq on pageload which rewrites the HTML code and my onSelect() function get hide. Thank you so much for the answer!